# How to solve receiving multiple IPN messages (same content) in one transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am testing my cart checkout with Codeigniter `paypal_lib`. The results I got from sandbox message :"VERIFIED" and also the function "validate_ipn" returns true. But the trouble I am facing here is my log file and order data containing the same data from paypal from time to time.

Below is my ipn validate:

```
function validate_ipn(){

    $url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);       
    $post_string="cmd=_notify-validate";     
    if ($this->CI->input->post())
    {
        foreach ($this->CI->input->post() as $field=>$value)
        { 
            $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value;
            $post_string .= '&' . $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        }
    }

    //$fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
            $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $err_num, $err_str, 30);
    if(!$fp)
    {
        $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
        return false;
    } 
    else
    { 
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
        while(!feof($fp))
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 

        fclose($fp); // close connection
    }

    if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response))
    {
        // Valid IPN transaction.
        $this->log_ipn_results(true);
        return true;         
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);  
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what I got in my log (nothing different).So many messages like this:

```
[04/24/2012 9:31 AM] - SUCCESS!
IPN POST Vars from Paypal:
mc_gross=11.00, protection_eligibility=Eligible, address_status=confirmed
, item_number1=3, tax=0.00, item_number2=5, payer_id=T4WYEY49NUK4Y, item_number3=6, address_street=1 Maire-Victorin, payment_date=00:28:18 Apr 24, 
2012 PDT, payment_status=Pending, charset=windows-1252, address_zip=M5A 1E1, mc_shipping=0.00, mc_handling=0.00, first_name=Test, address_country_code=CA, 
address_name=Test User, notify_version=3.4, custom=292aaf2e76b586a80c20f13c5b1d6997, payer_status=verified, business=tham21_1297141093_biz@yahoo.com, 
address_country=Canada, num_cart_items=3, mc_handling1=0.00, mc_handling2=0.00, mc_handling3=0.00, address_city=Toronto, verify_sign=AQwZI3e5UUeRN1fFRRAZwba0SCKvAK5Jh7SdLhAZdWaitG4t3SzIzk6D,
payer_email=tham21_1297133813_per@yahoo.com, mc_shipping1=0.00, mc_shipping2=0.00, mc_shipping3=0.00, tax1=0.00, tax2=0.00, tax3=0.00, txn_id=19366377KU1661939, 
payment_type=instant, last_name=User, address_state=Ontario, item_name1=Test 003 Product, receiver_email=tham21_1297141093_biz@yahoo.com, item_name2=Test 005 Product, 
item_name3=Test 006 Product, quantity1=1, quantity2=1, receiver_id=C7F8469MV6QVN, pending_reason=multi_currency, quantity3=1, txn_type=cart, mc_gross_1=2.00, mc_currency=EUR, 
mc_gross_2=4.00, mc_gross_3=5.00, residence_country=CA, test_ipn=1, transaction_subject=292aaf2e76b586a80c20f13c5b1d6997, payment_gross=, ipn_track_id=95d4aa9eb8b34, 

IPN Response from Paypal Server:
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK

8
VERIFIED
0



[04/24/2012 9:33 AM] - SUCCESS!
IPN POST Vars from Paypal:
mc_gross=11.00, protection_eligibility=Eligible, address_status=confirmed
, item_number1=3, tax=0.00, item_number2=5, payer_id=T4WYEY49NUK4Y, item_number3=6, address_street=1 Maire-Victorin, payment_date=00:28:18 Apr 24, 
2012 PDT, payment_status=Pending, charset=windows-1252, address_zip=M5A 1E1, mc_shipping=0.00, mc_handling=0.00, first_name=Test, address_country_code=CA, 
address_name=Test User, notify_version=3.4, custom=292aaf2e76b586a80c20f13c5b1d6997, payer_status=verified, business=tham21_1297141093_biz@yahoo.com, 
address_country=Canada, num_cart_items=3, mc_handling1=0.00, mc_handling2=0.00, mc_handling3=0.00, address_city=Toronto, verify_sign=AQwZI3e5UUeRN1fFRRAZwba0SCKvAK5Jh7SdLhAZdWaitG4t3SzIzk6D, 
payer_email=tham21_1297133813_per@yahoo.com, mc_shipping1=0.00, mc_shipping2=0.00, mc_shipping3=0.00, tax1=0.00, tax2=0.00, tax3=0.00, txn_id=19366377KU1661939, 
payment_type=instant, last_name=User, address_state=Ontario, item_name1=Test 003 Product, receiver_email=tham21_1297141093_biz@yahoo.com, item_name2=Test 005 Product, 
item_name3=Test 006 Product, quantity1=1, quantity2=1, receiver_id=C7F8469MV6QVN, pending_reason=multi_currency, quantity3=1, txn_type=cart, mc_gross_1=2.00, mc_currency=EUR, 
mc_gross_2=4.00, mc_gross_3=5.00, residence_country=CA, test_ipn=1, transaction_subject=292aaf2e76b586a80c20f13c5b1d6997, payment_gross=, ipn_track_id=95d4aa9eb8b34, 

IPN Response from Paypal Server:
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Apr 2012 07:33:44 GMT

8
VERIFIED
0
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now

Comment: Very odd -- how are you passing the IPN url to paypal? IIRC, you can set it in your account, and you can pass it in the payment process. Wonder if doing both is causing two notices? Also, don't discount a Paypal bug. I've fought a couple of problems that required numerous long phone calls with their staff and resulted in some action on their end to resolve it. Check your outbound process and account, then I suggest you contact them. Two notices about the same thing, 2 minutes apart seems... weird. Intermittent?

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying that this even happens, but until PayPal has resolved the issue on their end you need to develop a safeguard so you don't process the same payment twice.

The most common solution is to mark the transaction in the database as processed, change a status field or add a date. Then you check this value on each IPN message and if it's already set ignore the IPN (but log it).